# Change ImageView drawable of an inflated layout

Tags: android, file-handling, android-inflate

I want to change the drawable of imageview, that is saved to disk,, and is available. but when setting drawable, a NullPointerException occurs

The question is, how to change imageview drawable of inflated layout[Source image is "/sdcard/myappfolder/user.png"], the layout is inflated

Here's my part of code:

```
    intilt = itilt.inflate(R.layout.pic_container, null, false);    //layout is inflated successfully
    picCheck(); // method to check file availability, working perfect, if file exists, returns 1, else returns 0;
    if(picmark == 1){
        Bitmap pch = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.contimg);  //contimg is ImageView id from layout pic_container
        imageView.setImageBitmap(pch);  
        /**
        *  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        *  at com.package.packagename.javaact.onCreate(javaact.java:83)
        */
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found, setting Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: intilt = itilt.inflate(R.layout.pic_container, null, false);  can you see the view you inflated? You even haven't add it to anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```
imageView = (ImageView) intilt .findViewById(R.id.contimg);
```

Comment: Thanks. imageView = (ImageView) intilt.findViewById(R.id.contimg); //this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
//you should add it to somewhere. intilt = itilt.inflate(R.layout.pic_container,a existed View, true); 
intilt = itilt.inflate(R.layout.pic_container, null, false);    //layout is inflated successfully
    picCheck(); // method to check file availability, working perfect, if file exists, returns 1, else returns 0;
    if(picmark == 1){
        Bitmap pch = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        //if you have inflated it into somewhere, you can just use below.
        imageView = (ImageView)intilt.findViewById(R.id.contimg);  //contimg is ImageView id from layout pic_container
        imageView.setImageBitmap(pch);  
        /**
        *  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        *  at com.package.packagename.javaact.onCreate(javaact.java:83)
        */
    }
    else{
        Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found, setting Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Comment: I think you have a typo. Should be `intilt.findViewById`

Comment: Thanks. imageView = (ImageView) intilt.findViewById(R.id.contimg); //this worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
intilt = itilt.inflate(R.layout.pic_container, null, false);
picCheck();
if(picmark == 1){
    Bitmap pch = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
    imageView = (ImageView) intilt.findViewById(R.id.contimg); //Change here 
    imageView.setImageBitmap(pch);  
}
else{
    Toast.makeText(this, "File Not Found, setting Default", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks. imageView = (ImageView) intilt.findViewById(R.id.contimg); //this worked. Thanks.